# NetBeans Platform - getActions() on TopComponent not working correctly

Tags: java, netbeans, action

I am overriding the getActions() method to customize the behavior of the popup menu when my TopComponent tab is right clicked.  The problem is, the actions I specify are not coming out correctly.

```
@Override
public Action[] getActions() {
    return new Action[]{new A(), new B()};
}
```

I would expect that when I right click, my actions A and B would appear.

Instead I see

A

Minimize Window

B

How do I get minimize window either to not show up, or to show up in a different place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bizarre instance where A and B were ContextSensitive actions but in the XML layer they were declared as AlwaysEnabled.  Once I fixed to put them as contextSensitive, this issue went away.